# "Легок на помине"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "легок на помине", что оно изначально значило?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В старину поминали не только усопших (за упокой), но и отсутствующих живых (за здравие). И, если дорога у такого человека была легкой и он быстро возвращался, говорили, что он "легок на помине".